# VB.net Network Graph code/algorithm

Tags: vb.net, graph

For a school project we need to visualise a computer network graph. The number of computers with specific properties are read from an XML file, and then a graph should be created. Ad random computers are added and removed.

Is there any open source project or algorithm that could help us visualising this in VB.net? Or would you suggest us to switch to java.

Update: We eventually switched java and used the Jung libraries because this was easier for us to understand and implement.

Comment: Probably need the homework tag adding to this question...

Comment: What are you actually being asked to do, here? I mean, what is the main focus of this assignment? Are you looking at inputting/outputting XML files? Graphics? Object-oriented programming? Understanding what you're looking for would help in knowing what kind of answer to give.

Comment: The last sentence. We are looking for code that could help us display the network.

Answer (score 1):

[QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) is an excellent interface for use with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

[image: Example Graph]